# Weighted average grouped by country and year

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, average, weighted

I have a code which calls several apis from the UN comtrade database iterating through years. It then appends these together into a single dataset of all reporters and years from 1991 to 2018. I am trying to then get the average of the trade value weighted by the net weight for each country each year.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np

base = "http://comtrade.un.org/api/get?"
maxrec = "50000"
item = "C"
freq = "A"
px="H0"
ps="all"
r="all"
p="0"
rg="2"
cc="AG2"
fmt="json"

comtrade = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Year', 'Reporter Code', 'Reporter', 'Commodity Code', 'Commodity', 'Trade Value (US$)'])

for year in range(1991,2018):
    print(r)
    ps="{}".format(year)
    url = base + "max=" + maxrec + "&" "type=" + item + "&" + "freq=" + freq + "&" + "px=" +px + "&" + "ps=" + str(ps) + "&" + "r="+ str(r) + "&" + "p=" + p + "&" + "rg=" +rg + "&" + "cc=" + cc + "&" + "fmt=" + fmt
#    print(url)
    t = requests.get(url)
    x = t.json()
    new = pd.DataFrame(x["dataset"])
    comtrade = comtrade.append(new)
group = comtrade.groupby([ 'rtCode', 'yr'])
finalvalue = group.apply(lambda x: np.average(x['TradeValue'], 
weights=x['NetWeight']))
```

This may be obvious but here is where the problem seems to be coming here:

```
group = comtrade.groupby([ 'rtCode', 'yr'])
finalvalue = group.apply(lambda x: np.average(x['TradeValue'], weights=x['NetWeight']))
```

where I get an error of:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: `df['NetWeight']` is None for a sizeable portion of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the below description at [this example URL from your scraping](https://comtrade.un.org/api/get?max=50000&type=C&freq=A&px=H0&ps=1991&r=all&p=0&rg=2&cc=AG2&fmt=json), null is a main feature of the data which is being entered in your data frame as "None".

You can change your None type using "fillna" from Pandas. I used 0 in this example which could work with your groupby, or you could do "nan" since "NA groups in GroupBy are automatically excluded," per their docs.

```
from numpy import nan
comtrade =  comtrade.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

[image]